# C# list question

Tags: c#, list, merge, ienumerable

What would be the nice way to make the following action:

```
List<IEnumerable<T>> listOfEnumerables = Get...();

List<T> listOfObjects = new List<T>();

// I want 'listOfObjects' to contain every element from every enumerable
// in 'listOfEnumerables'.
```

**Is there any beautiful way to make this instead of the following:**

```
foreach (var enumerable in listOfEnumerables)
{
    listOfObjects.AddRange(enumerable);
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: That very much depends on your definition of beauty.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use LINQ:

```
List<T> listOfObjects = listOfEnumerables.SelectMany(s => s).ToList();
```

Comment: The beauty of LINQ though - this is not necessarily any more efficient (it might be, but then it might not), and it is certainly harder to read for me.

Comment: The only thing I don't find beautiful here is the identity function. Why isn't there a `Fun.Id` somewhere in the framework? :(

Comment: It's not hard to read when you know what SelectMany does. It would be more "beautiful" if a parameterless SelectMany existed, though.

Answer (score 4):

```
listOfEnumerables.ForEach(i => listOfObjects.AddRange(i));
```

Comment: ... or just `.ForEeach(listOfObjects.AddRange)`